# ValueError in python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am constantly getting this error "`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)in for(word,tag) in grp:"`
This what I have tried
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import nltk
    import itertools
    import ast
    import collections
    import sys
    import re
    import time

```
f=open('test.txt','r')
text1=f.read()
text2=text1.rstrip()
text3=text2.strip()
#text3=tuple(text1)
#print(text3)

print("text3")


train_data=text3


print(train_data)

f=open('test1.txt','r')
text5=f.read()
#text6=text5.splitlines()
text6=text5.strip()
text7=text6.rstrip()
orig_data=text7
```

Comment: Please correct the indentations

Comment: `train_data` seems to just be a line you read from a file. When you iterate over a string, you get a characters, not tuples.

Comment: my train_data is in this format                                                           [[('my','JJ'),('name','NN'),('Ashish','NNP')]]

Comment: train_data is just one large string and grp will then be just one character at a time. you cant move that into (word,tag) that's why you get the error. You will need to read the data differently to achieve what you actually want. can you post a snippet of how the text file looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `train_data` is just a str. Notice how you read it from a file and don't do anything to change it into code. If you want to confirm, call `print(type(train_data))`. You'll get `<class 'str'>`.

You can iterate through a `str` with a for loop, that's why your first loop works, but in your second loop, you're just looping over the characters in the original str.

If you want to use it as actual data, you must parse it and turn it into a Python data structure. DO NOT USE EVAL FOR THIS. Instead use the `ast` library (safer and more stable in case of mistakes in your data):

```
import ast
# … later …
train_data = ast.literal_eval(text3)
```

Then go on and use `train_data` as you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open('C://Users//DELL//Desktop//test.txt','r')
text1=f.read()
text2=text1.rstrip()
text3=text2.strip()
#text3=tuple(text1)
#print(text3)
print("text3")
train_data=text3
print(train_data)

f=open('C://Users//DELL//Desktop//test1.txt','r')
text5=f.read()
#text6=text5.splitlines()
text6=text5.strip()
text7=text6.strip()
orig_data=text7
print(orig_data)

orgword=[]
orgtags=[]
#orig_data=train_data
#print("original data")
#print(orig_data)
for grp in train_data:
    for word in grp:
        orgword.append(word)
        #orgtags.append(tag)

print("Original Words")
print(orgword)
print("Original Tags")
print(orgtags)

#fix it...!!!(U get word in test)
```